# How to Display the Facebook login page when button is clicked

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to display display the Facebook login page in my app when the user is not signed-in yet. I'm using Facebook SDK for posting a status message on the users Facebook wall when the user allows the app.

Heres the code:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    // post to wall
    @try {
        [self postStatusMethod];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Error on posting to fb: %@", exception);
    }
    @finally {

    }
} else {
    // try to open session with existing valid token
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"read_stream",
                            @"publish_actions",
                            nil];
    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
    if([FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO]) {
        // post to wall
        @try {
            [self postStatusMethod];
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Error on posting to fb: %@", exception);
        }
        @finally {

        }
    } else {
        // you need to log the user
        [self userLogin];
    }
}
```

how do i create the userLogin function so that is will display this:

[image]

Then, go back to the same view controller. i am using Facebook sdk.

Comment: Facbook SDK comes with the sample codes. In facebook login view will be helpful to you.

Comment: i already read those sample and it all requires me to use the login button. i want to display the page when the user wants to post a status update but he/she is not logged in

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i build the code:

```
-(void) userLogin {
NSLog(@"Clicked!");
// If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
    || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

    // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
    // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
} else {
    // Open a session showing the user the login UI
    // You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

     }];
}
}
```

But it goes back to my main menu not on the same menu where i click it.

Comment: Any suggestions on doing it?